# Correct approach to get JSON node length in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this simple JSON file that supposed to be one array *Paths* with 3 arrays (Path1, Path2, Path3) of objects.

```
{
    "Paths":
    
        {
            "Path1": [{"x":"4","y":"182"},{"x":"220","y":"186"}],
            "Path2": [{"x":"4","y":"222"},{"x":"256","y":"217"}],
            "Path3": [{"x":"6","y":"170"},{"x":"216","y":"183"}]
        }
    
}
```

Considering an online example that I found I am doing this to get the length of *Paths* node:

```
// It's Phaser 3 (JS game framework)
// this.cache.json.get('data') -> returns me the JSON contents
var json = this.cache.json.get('data');
for (var pos in json.Paths) {
    var len = parseInt(json.Paths[pos].length)+1;
    console.log(len);
}
```

Although it *works* I would like to know if this is the correct approach because it seems to be too much code only to get a node length.

Thanks!

Comment: No need to use parseInt() as array `length` will always be integer. Why the `+1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are trying to print the length of each path or get total length of all paths, if you want to print the length of each path then you can use `map`

```js
let lengths = Object.values(json.Paths).map(path => path.length + 1)
console.log(lengths)
```

which will output

```
[ 3, 3, 3 ]
```

or `forEach` like you did

```js
Object.values(json.Paths).forEach(path => console.log(path.length + 1))
```

if you need the total you can use `reduce`

```js
let nodeLength = Object.values(json.Paths).reduce((acc, path) => acc + path.length, 0)
```

which will give you `6`

Edit: since in the comment you said you needed to know how many elements are in your object, you can use

```js
Object.keys(json.Paths).length
```

to get that

Comment: It did the trick. I was confusing things but this cleared up my mind. In fact I was looking for the length of the Paths array (3), but then lengths.length did the trick. Thanks a log for this! :-)

Comment: @YanKleber if you just need to know how many elements are in the `Paths` object, I updated my answer to include that too

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to get a count of all the points in all paths you could access them using Object.values() and then reduce()

```js
const data ={
    "Paths":
    
        {
            "Path1": [{"x":"4","y":"182"},{"x":"220","y":"186"}],
            "Path2": [{"x":"4","y":"222"},{"x":"256","y":"217"}],
            "Path3": [{"x":"6","y":"170"},{"x":"216","y":"183"}]
        }
    
}

const numPoints = Object.values(data.Paths).reduce((a,c) => (a + c.length), 0)

console.log(numPoints)
```